# Minimal permissions to read performance of indexes in SQL server

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database, sql-server-2019, azure-sql-managed-instance

What minimal permissions can be assigned to a database user so that user can read performance of indexes on tables/views in that database? I am using latest version of `SQL Server` and `Azure SQL Managed Instance`.

Comment: "*read performance of indexes*" - Could you please elaborate what you mean by this?...Do you mean permissions to view the execution plan of a given query?

Answer (score 0):

Let me know if the new server role "##MS_ServerPerformanceStateReader##" on SQL 2022 helps you achieve what you are looking for. Please read [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/authentication-access/server-level-roles?view=sql-server-ver16#fixed-server-level-roles-introduced-in-sql-server-2022).

This new role allows any member to view key performance metrics through Dynamic Management Views (DMV) but not the same full rights as members of the sysadmin role. You no longer need to assign VIEW SERVER STATE permissions to users that need access to DMVs like sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats.

Comment: He's using 2019 not 2022.

Comment: In that case VIEW SERVER STATE is needed.

Comment: Depends on what OP is trying to do, as my question on his Post asks. If he wants to read execution plans, yes. If he literally wants the metrics on what indexes are being used, then that's in the DMVs and he shouldn't need `VIEW SERVER STATE`.

Comment: He requested an answer from me on this https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/316811/permission-to-grant-select-update-delete-alter-on-all-tables/316834?noredirect=1#comment628929_316834. That is the reason I tried to provide my best answer with the information provided